# Loading Apache FOP configuration file in 2.6 throws a NullPointerException

Tags: java, apache-fop

I upgrade Apache FOP from `2.3` to `2.7` and I now get a `NullPointerException`.  I have isolated the issue to a change between version `2.5` and `2.6` within the function `FopConfParser(File fopConfFile, ResourceResolver resourceResolver)` in the file `org.apache.fop.apps.FopConfParser.java`, line 144:

`2.5`: `this(new FileInputStream(fopConfFile), fopConfFile.toURI(), resourceResolver);`

`2.6`: `this(new FileInputStream(fopConfFile), fopConfFile.getParentFile().toURI(), resourceResolver);`

The code below demonstrates the issue:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.fop.apps.FopConfParser;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class Test
{
    private static final String FOP_CONFIGURATION_FILE = "fopConfiguration.xml";


    static
    {
        try
        {
            File configurationFile = new File( FOP_CONFIGURATION_FILE );
            FopConfParser fopConfParser = new FopConfParser( configurationFile );
        }
        catch( SAXException saxException ) { saxException.printStackTrace(); }
        catch( IOException ioException ) { ioException.printStackTrace(); }
        catch( Exception exception ) { exception.printStackTrace(); }
    }


    public static void main( String args[ ] ) { }
}
```

To test requires a few steps:

1. [Download](https://archive.apache.org/dist/xmlgraphics/fop/binaries/) FOP binary releases `2.5` and `2.6` and extract each archive.
2. Save the test program above as `Test.java` and create sub-directories called `2.5` and `2.6`.
3. From the `2.5` extracted archive, copy `conf/fop.xconf` to the same directory as `Test.java` and copy `build/fop.jar` and `lib/*.jar` files  to the `2.5` sub-directory.  Similarly for `2.6`.
4. To compile: `javac -cp "2.5/*" Test.java`; to run: `java -cp "2.5/*:." Test`.  Similarly for `2.6`.

Any ideas on why the configuration file is no longer being located (perhaps to do with classpath) and any ideas please on how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem when upgrading from 2.5 to 2.8.
Just use:

```
File configurationFile = new File( FOP_CONFIGURATION_FILE ).getAbsoluteFile();
```

to get file with apsolute path.

NullPointerException comes from getParentFile() which returns null if file's path doesn't have at least one parent level. My guess is that developers expect for constructor input either file with absolute or file with relative path which has at least one upper level. To me it looks more like a bug than a feature.